# Binding Listbox to Array of Lists

Tags: .net, wpf, list, data-binding, listbox

I have 10 Listboxes and an array of 1000 Lists of string.
I need to fill the listboxes from the Array dpending on the Array Index. Is this possible with binding or have to do it manually?

Comment: Provide more information with code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyArrayOfLists[0]}".../>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyArrayOfLists[1]}".../>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyArrayOfLists[3]}".../>
...
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyArrayOfLists[Index]}".../> <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyArrayOfLists[Index+1]}".../> <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyArrayOfLists[Index+2]}".../> So this is not possible right?

Comment: @Moonwalker031 - In the binding expression you can only specify constant values (as in my example). Expressions will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I mean this statment is not possible right in XAML? But can it be done through code?

---

I have listboxes named listBox1, listBox2, listBox3 etc. Is there a way to name then like an array - listbox[1], listbox[2], listbox[3] - so that I can access them like an array - listBox[Index]?